# Elapsed time since function last call

Tags: java

I am trying to write a method that will return the amount of time that has passed since the method was last called, it looks like this:

```
package JGame.Util;

import java.util.Date;

public class Util{

    protected static Long lastTime = null;

    public static long getLastTime(){
        long time = new Date().getTime();
        if(Util.lastTime == null){
            Util.lastTime = time;
            return 0;
        }
        long ftime = time - Util.lastTime;
        Util.lastTime = time;
        return ftime;
    }
}
```

I am then calling the method like this, within a key press event:

```
long lastTime = Util.getLastTime();
if(lastTime > 1000){
    return;
}
System.out.println(lastTime);
```

The problem I am having, is that when the key is pressed down it prints out `lastTime`, but it should only be printed out once every second.

here is the output:

```
122
6
7
13
9
7
10
9
10
```

While holding down the key, I was expecting all to be very close to 1 second intervals. but the numbers are not even close.

Comment: (Off-topic) If you want the time as a `long`, use `System.currentTimeMillis()` rather than `new Date().getTime()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got your condition the wrong way round. Look at this:

```
if (lastTime > 1000) {
    return;
}
```

That's saying if the method was last called *more* than a second ago, don't print anything out. So if you call it lots of times in quick succession, it will *always* go past this check after the first time.

I suspect you *think* you want

```
if (lastTime < 1000) {
    return;
}
```

... but that still won't actually do what you want - because now if you press execute that code very frequently, it will *only* go past that check the first time.

You need to only reset the "last printed" time *if* it was more than a second ago.

Oh, and I suggest you use `System.nanoTime()` instead of `new Date().getTime()` - it's guaranteed to be monotonically increasing, and is designed for measuring time differences rather than a "current" wall time. I'd also make this *not* just use a static variable. I'd create a class which allows a "threshold" and has a method to see whether that threshold has passed, and reset the timer if so:

```
public class TimeRegulator {
    private final long periodMilliseconds;

    private long lastTick = 0L; // 1970 will be long before the current time :)

    public TimeRegulator(long periodMilliseconds) {
        this.periodMilliseconds = periodMilliseconds;
    }

    public boolean checkTime() {
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        long diffNanos = now - lastTick;
        long diffMilliseconds = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(diffNanos);
        if (diffMilliseconds < periodMilliseconds) {
            return false;
        }
        lastTick = now;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Also, consider injecting an abstraction of "get the current time" in order to make all of this testable... and consider using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead of the built-in libraries, too :)

Comment: `System.nanoTime()` should be used instead of `System.currentTimeMillis()` for calculating elapsed time.  Otherwise, +1.

Comment: @Vulcan: That's true, I forgot about that. Will fix.

Comment: Best, most detailed answer.  Unfortunately, I can't upvote it twice.

Comment: So, I did `if(tm.checkTime())` and it always enters the if, and runs `return` basically checkTIme is always returning `false`

Comment: @RyanNaddy: It shouldn't if you call it often enough. I've just checked it myself, and it works fine. What did you pass in for `periodMilliseconds`?

Comment: @RyanNaddy: You're not creating a new instance every time you call it, are you? You need to keep a single instance for each "ticker" you need.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning if the last call was **more** than 1 second away, I think you should return if it was **less** than 1 second away.

What your code will never do (unless corrected) is print a value higher than 1000.

Answer (score 2):

Your if statement is inverted:

```
if(lastTime > 1000){
    return;
}
```

You are returning if the last interval is more than a second, which is the opposite of what you are describing. Try changing this to `if(lastTime < 1000){`

Otherwise I can't see anything wrong with your code.